# DIV margin some value, inside DIV with margin auto, not working

Tags: html, css

```
<body>  
<div id="wrapper" style="margin:auto;width:100px">
<div id="inner" style="margin-left:10px;">
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

For the code above i am unable to set margin for the div "inner".

I have a blog whose layout has a "date" box(40px wide) set 20px(left) outside the wrapper of the content.

Please help.

Comment: When margin fails, there's always padding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would show you an example on JS fiddle, but its down at the moment.

That code should be working, maybe its because there is no inner content there at the moment.

You could always try

```
<div id="wrapper" style="margin:auto;width:90px; padding-left:10px">
```

For the same outcome :)

Comment: To make the code short, i did not include any content. Settings padding is not working for me. The wrapper doesnt use paddings given in css.